# The loop adds several elements to the array JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have a problem in loop with adding data to array. It is working like this: if we have 1 array - added 1 element to array. If we have 2 and more - added 2 and more elements.

Code example:

```
push: function (arr, index, data) {
    let i = index;

    for (index; index < object.stack.phone.number.length; index++) {
        console.log(index < object.stack.phone.number.length);

        if (arr[i].length <= 4) {
            object.pushData(arr[i], data);
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }

}
```

Input: **arr** - array, where we pushing data. For example: `'0': []`; **index** - in what index we pushing, here we have `'0'`; **data** - this is some data, for example `'Hello world'`

Desired result: I have a lot of arrays '0' ... and more, I want them to fill in one by one, until one gets 5, it does not have to go to the next one

What's problem here? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome. Can you please post some input and some output?

Comment: `if (arr[i].length <= 4) {  if (arr[i].length === 5) {` that's some flawed logic. It can't be `===5` if it's `<=4`.

Comment: @Jeremy Thille, yes, thanks, It wasn't necessary to use this logic

Comment: Can you add input format and desired output?

Comment: I believe there may be a problem with `let i = index`. I think JS creates a reference, which means that if you do `i++`, then `index` will also be incremented. It's the same variable, you're not copying the value into a new variable. Try with `i = 0 + index`, which will separate `i` and `index`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure can't use **splice** function?

> `arr.splice(index, 0, item);` will insert `item` into `arr` at the
>   specified index (deleting `0` items first, that is, it's just an
>   insert).

Comment: Yes i'm sure bro)